# Join strings with a separator, ignoring empty strings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to form a variable.

If it is not `null` or empty or `undefined` I don't want to append the `@` symbol to it:

```
var T1  = 'Popcorn'
var T2  = 'Icecreams'
var T3  = '';
var T4  = '';

if(T1!=''||T2!=''||T3!=''||T4!='')

reqstr = T1+'@'+T2+'@'+T3+'@'+T4;

alert(reqstr);
```

Right now the output is:

> Popcorn@Icecreams@@

If the variable is empty I don't want to append `@`, meaning I require only:

> Popcorn@Icecreams

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20rxg855/1/).

Answer (score 9):

Not the clearest Q.; try this:

```
[T1,T2,T3,T4].filter(Boolean).join('@');
```

And if you want to allow numbers in your variables, you need to do a bit more work:

```
[T1,T2,T3,T4].filter(function(x){
    return typeof x === 'number' || x;
}).join('@');
```

And to allow numbers, but filter out `NaN`:

```
[T1,T2,T3,T4].filter(function(x){
    return x === 0 || x;
}).join('@');
```

Etc., depending on the specification.

Comment: `join`... Why didn't I think of that. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(T1!=''||T2!=''||T3!=''||T4!=''){
    reqstr = T1+'@'+T2+'@'+T3+'@'+T4;
    reqstr = reqstr.replace(/@@/g, '@').replace(/(^@+)|(@+$)/g, '')
}
```

The first `replace` removes all double `@`'s from the string. The second one removes any leading or trailing ones.

Comment: `var T1  = 'Popcorn' var T2  = '' var T3  = ''; var T4  = '';` shouldn't return `Popcorn`?

Comment: @laaposto: Nice find. Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var T1  = 'Popcorn'
 var T2  = 'Icecreams'
var T3  = '';
var T4  = '';



reqstr = (T1)?(T1+'@'):'';
reqstr += (T2)?(T2+'@'):'';
reqstr +=(T3)?(T3+'@'):'';
reqstr +=(T4)?(T4+'@'):'';

 console.log(reqstr);
 alert(reqstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the variables into an array, `filter`ing out all empty values and then `join`ing it using `@` as a separator.

```
var T1  = 'Popcorn'
var T2  = 'Icecreams'
var T3  = '';
var T4  = '';

var arr = [T1, T2, T3, T4];
arr = arr.filter(function(e){ return e;}); // The filtering function returns `true` if e is not empty.
reqstr = arr.join("@")

console.log(reqstr);
alert(reqstr);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20rxg855/4/)